# CSS Background image not showing

Tags: css

I have a background image that I want to show in a div floated right.

Here is the css

```
<style>
.myclass {
background-image: url('images/myimage.png') no-repeat 0 0;
float:right;
background-size:80px 80px;
}
</style>
```

Then I have a list:

```
<ul>
<li>
<div class="myclass">&nbsp;</div>
<p>Hello</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

For some reason the image is not showing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `background-image` selector but using it as if it were the shorthand `background` rule.

Use: `background: url('images/myimage.png') no-repeat 0 0;`

You'll also need to specify a width and height to the div as the float collapses it and the `&nbsp;` will only give it a marginal height and width.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FQCzu/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it like this

```
.myclass{
    background: url('images/myimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

you have to give it certain properties regarding it's height and width otherwise it won't show. One suggestion is this, that you check out the dimensions of you image in the folder and define the size accordingly in height and width. Good luck!

Comment: You should use 4 spaces instead of `>` to highlight your code.

Comment: absolutely, will do it! I am new at SO so just learning things, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `background-image` use `background` for your CSS attribute.

http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

You may also need to add a background-color before the url() property.

Comment: No background-color is needed. In the shorthand `background` selector the color is optional and transparent is the default.

Answer (score 1):

```
background:url('img_tree.png') right no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be your folder path.. have you tried ../images/?